# Mathematically proving that field in a conductor is zero for equilibrium condition using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

I was reading this article [here](https://medium.com/cantors-paradise/the-method-of-lagrange-multipliers-85da7ae86799) and near the half of it, the author discusses a way to prove that potential is a body is constant is the state which minimizes potential of a body. I was able to follow the proof well enough till the last step:

$$\bbox[6px,border:2px solid red]{\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_o} \int_V \frac{\rho(r')\,dV' }{|r-r'|} + \phi_{\operatorname{ext}} (r) =\lambda}$$

The author arrives at this equation and states that from the above equation we can say that $\rho(r)$ is the distribution which makes the potential a constant and it is said that it completes the proof of original statement.. but I don't quite understand how it does.

I am looking for how we can understand that the above equation implies that the potential inside conductor is constant. Also how it doesn't imply that the potential outside the conductor is also constant.

Comment: He/she is saying that the first term on the LHS is $\phi_{\text{inner}}$ so, the LHS is $\phi_{\text{inside}}$. That whole is equal to the constant $\lambda$ for every $\mathbf{r}$ inside the conductor. Or, is your question why the integral is equal to $\phi_{\text{inner}}$?

Comment: Ohh @MarcoCiafa I got it now, the I was thinking by mistake was the total potential was given as the first term. Now I understand that it is just the potential caused by charges inside, thank you.

Comment: How does this arguement change when we talk of points outside the volume of container @MarcoCiafa (as in how do we say that potential may or may not be non zero for outside conductor?)

Comment: I think it's becuase $\phi_{\text{ext}}$ is only defined as the potential of the outer carges $\textit{inside}$ the conductor. The function that you are extremising is the energy stored, so the potential he/she is defining is only defined a priori inside becuase it's where it matters. In the expression for $U$, where first appears $\phi_{\text{ext}}$, he/she integrates over $V$, the region inside. You can say nothing about the outside, at least with that function.

Comment: Please let me know if you understood what I said and if I should write and answer.

Comment: I mean your argument made sense to me but I felt it wasn't convincing enough, I went back and read about the equation here in [Feynman lectures](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_08.html)  and there the integral is over all space. I don't know how you couldn't use this same arguement for the function he defines. Sorry if I am missing something basic, I'm a bit new to working multiple integrals in physics :^) @MarcoCiafa

Comment: Oh wait I just realized for the whole space to have electrostatic equilibrium, it would need constant potential , so it works in the other case as well , right? @MarcoCiafa

Comment: The integrand is $\rho\phi_{\text{ext}}$ and $\rho$ is the charge density of the conductor so even if you integrate in the whole space $\rho = 0 $ outside the conductor. That's why I said you are saying nothing about $\phi_{\text{ext}}$ outside. (I.e the energy is given by the charges in the conductor and the potential where the conductor ends ups being).

Comment: The potential doesn't has to be constant in all the space to be in equilibrium. That would be the same as saying there is field nowhere. The conductor in that scenario is fixed in space (it's shape is fixed), the charges are allowed to move. Equilibrium in this context means the free charges inside the conductor are in equilibrium (i.e. there is no field in the conductor).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119177/discussion-between-buraian-and-marcociafa).