# Gravitational field inside a conductor

Tags: newtonian-gravity, gauss-law

[Using self-energy and Lagrange multipliers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/611370/), we can prove that for equilibrium the charges will distribute inside the body in such a way that the field goes to zero/potential is constant inside the body, and due to Poisson equation:

$$ \nabla^2 V = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_o}.$$

LHS is zero inside the body, so it is clear that there is no charge inside the body.

Now, what would happen if we applied the same argument for gravitational mass and potential? We can define analogue to Gauss law for gravitation and we could also discuss similar self energy concepts [(see here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity). From proving this, it should suggest that the mass density inside the body is zero for equilibrium.. which is a bit weird?

What is the intuition behind this result or is my conclusion wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key difference happens right at the start.  The potential energy of two point charges is $q_1 q_2/(4 \pi \epsilon_0 r)$, while the potential energy of two point masses is $-G m_1 m_2/ r$.  We can therefore adapt the notation of [the article linked in your previous question](https://medium.com/cantors-paradise/the-method-of-lagrange-multipliers-85da7ae86799) so long as we replace charge density by mass density and $1/4 \pi \epsilon_0 \to -G$.

In particular, the self-energy functional for a gravitational object becomes
$$
U[\rho(r)] = - \frac{G}{2} \int \, dV \int \, dV' \left[ \frac{\rho(\mathbf{r}) \rho'(\mathbf{r})}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'| }\right],
$$
assuming no external potential.  In effect, this "flips the sign" of the potential energy, meaning that what would have been a minimum-energy extremum in the electrostatic case (i.e., constant potential in the region $V$) becomes a *maximum*-energy extremum in the gravitational case.  Such an extremum would, of course, be unstable.  In fact, this potential energy function has no global minimum, since it is unbounded below.  For a fixed amount of mass, $U$ can be made arbitrarily negative simply by compressing the mass further.

As an aside, this suggests an interesting brain-teaser:  Suppose a mass distribution with a fixed amount of total mass $M$ is confined to a given volume $V$.  For what density configuration of this mass $\rho(\mathbf{r})$ is the self-energy of the mass maximized?  The answer, according to the above logic, is the configuration for which the gravitational potential is constant everywhere inside $V$.

Answer (score 3):

The problem around this line of argument is that the following prerequisites of said electrical property are not satisfied for gravity.

1. a conductor by definition conducts electric charges (while disspating their energy according to Ohm's law), which is the reason why in equilibrium there can be no tangential component of the electric field (otherwise the charges would still be moving)
2. electric force between like charges is repulsive, which is the reason why charges repel until all of them are on the surface (which is the their lowest energy state)

Neither property is possessed by gravity. Gravitational charges (masses) attract each other. There is no such thing as a gravitational conductor, that confines charges (masses) to a defined volume and takes care that currents dissipate energy until they are in equilibrium. But the main problem remains 2.

As far as I remember, one can find the electrical property also by the method of mirror charges, which again is not possible for gravity because gravitational masses have no mirrors (negative mass or energy), at least as of today.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a fair analogy you need to consider the uniformly charged (insulating) sphere for the electrostatic case.  And compare this with a sphere with uniform mass density. Then in both cases the potential inside goes like $r^2$ and the laplacean is a constant, but not zero.

Comment: Why do you say it is fair only to compare w/ insulating sphere?

Comment: Because you are considering a sphere with uniform mass density for the gravitational case.  Don't you? If you consider a shell,  then the density is zero inside,  again for both cases.

Comment: Yes but electrostatic theorem is also true if we had began with uniform charge density (If I am not mistaken)

Comment: What do you mean by "electrostatic theorem?

Comment: The theorem proven in the linked stack, the thomsons theorem theorem states that to reach equilibrium, charge redistributes such that the potential is constant/ charge resides on surface of conductor

Comment: But inside an insulator the charges do not re-distribute, the field is not zero and the potential is not constant.  So you can have an insulator with uniform volume charge density.  At least theoretically.  And for the gravitational case you don't have the analogous of a conductor anyway.