# No net charge in conductor or no charge at all? Electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

I understand that there can be no net charge in a conductor because any moving free electrons would induce a countering electric field that would then cause the net E field inside a conductor to be zero. I also understand that net charge is distributed on the surface of a conductor in attempts for all surface charges to repel each other. But does this mean there is simply no net charge in a conductor? Or just no charge at all? Does all charge have to exist on the surface? Or only net charge?

Comment: The actual thi g to show is complicated. You need Thompson theorem irrc

Comment: Right. No _net_ charge inside a conductor. Any net charge will move to the surfaces and never inside the conductor. If you consider the protons and electrons of the atoms inside it, then there is - but that is not considered net charge.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/611370/236734. Once you have the previous result you can consider about charge since any possible gauss surface would give 0 flux

Answer (score 1):

Since conductors are made of atoms, which are made of particles with charge, there are still charges in conductors. There is no *net* charge within a conductor; any net charge resides on the surface(s).